# how to draw the following picture quickly and curly brace?

Tags: tikz-pic, tikz-graphdrawing

I know that this picture contains only line but I want to ask how to draw it quickly with tikzpicture? Moreover, how I can draw the curly brace (}) in the figure?

[image]

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @marmot: Really hot curry?

Comment: The speed of the drawing will depend pretty much on your processor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An almost complete reproduction of your drawing. Hope the next time you have enough time to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw (0,0) -- (10,0) node [right] {$\ell_1$};
\draw (0,1.5) -- (10,1.5) node [right] {$\ell_2$};
\draw (0,3.5) -- (10,3.5) node [right] (li) {$\ell_{i\phantom{+1}}$};
\draw (0,5) -- (10,5) node [right] (lj) {$\ell_{i+1}$};
\draw (0,7) -- (10,7) node [right] {$\ell_n$};
\draw[decoration={brace},decorate,transform
canvas={xshift=1.5em,yshift=0em},thick] (lj.north) -- (li.south)
node[right=3pt,midway] {$i$th climb}; % curly brace
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (0,0)--(1,0);
\draw (0,0) node [star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25,fill=black,draw,inner sep=1.3pt] {};
\draw[latex-latex] (0,-0.2)--(1,-0.2) node[below=2pt,midway] {$x_1$};
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (1,0)--(2,1.5);
\draw[densely dashed] (1,0) -- (1,1.7);
\draw[densely dashed] (2,0) -- (2,1.7);
\draw[latex-latex] (1,1.7)--(2,1.7) node[above=2pt,midway] {$d_1$};
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (2,1.5)--(3,1.5);
\draw[latex-latex] (2,1.3)--(3,1.3) node[below=2pt,midway] {$x_2$};
\draw[densely dashed] (0,2.5) -- (10,2.5);
\draw[-latex,thick,dashed, draw=red] (3,1.5)--(4.25,3.5);
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (4.25,3.5)--(5.25,3.5);
\draw[latex-latex] (4.25,3.7)--(5.25,3.7) node[above=2pt,midway] {$x_i$};
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (5.25,3.5)--(6.25,5);
\draw[densely dashed] (5.25,3.5) -- (5.25,5.2);
\draw[densely dashed] (6.25,5) -- (6.25,5.2);
\draw[latex-latex] (5.25,5.2)--(6.25,5.2) node[above=2pt,midway] {$d_i$};
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (6.25,5)--(7.25,5);
\draw[densely dashed] (0,6) -- (10,6);
\draw[-latex,thick, dashdotted, draw=red] (7.25,5)--(8.5,7);
\draw[-latex,thick, draw=red] (8.5,7)--(9.5,7);
\draw (10,7) node [star, star points=5, star point ratio=2.25,fill=black,draw,inner sep=1.3pt] {};
\draw[latex-latex] (8.5,6.8)--(9.5,6.8) node[below=2pt,midway] {$x_n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]